# How to update node veriosn in AWS amplify instance which is a domain and hosted using Route53

Tags: aws-amplify

my build getting failed and in Front end task its failing dwith below log

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2023-10-06T19:20:02.795Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-10-06T19:20:02.797Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@astrojs/prism@3.0.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@astrojs/telemetry@3.0.2',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-10-06T19:20:02.798Z [WARNING]: npm
2023-10-06T19:20:02.798Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'astro@3.2.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.14.1', npm: '>=6.14.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2023-10-06T19:20:15.722Z [INFO]: added 576 packages, and audited 577 packages in 16s
2023-10-06T19:20:15.726Z [INFO]: 227 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2023-10-06T19:20:15.742Z [INFO]: 4 vulnerabilities (3 low, 1 moderate)
                                 To address issues that do not require attention, run:
                                 npm audit fix
                                 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
                                 npm audit fix --force
                                 Run `npm audit` for details.
2023-10-06T19:20:15.756Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-10-06T19:20:15.756Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2023-10-06T19:20:16.116Z [INFO]: > grateful-galaxy@0.0.1 build
                                 > astro build
2023-10-06T19:20:16.234Z [WARNING]: Node.js v16.19.0 is not supported by Astro!
                                    Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version: ">=18.14.1"
2023-10-06T19:20:16.236Z [INFO]: AWS CodeBuild CI Environment Detected!
                                 Additional steps may be needed to set your Node.js version:
2023-10-06T19:20:16.237Z [INFO]: Documentation: https://docs.astro.build/guides/deploy
2023-10-06T19:20:16.244Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-10-06T19:20:16.245Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-10-06T19:20:16.357Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-10-06T19:20:16.358Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

for AWS [here is the build log](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/home?region=us-east-1#/d1c6hzkoiamnhy/develop/15?step=BUILD)

so my question is how to update node js version in AWS Amplify instance which is hosted on a domain with Route53. dont know issue is in Route 53 or AWS Amplify script.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just use an official node image from [node's ECR repository](https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/library/node).

Go to your amplify application in AWS. Click `Build Settings` under `App Settings` on the sidebar.

Under `Build image settings`, click `Edit`.

In the popup, under `Build image`, change the dropdown option to `Build image`. In the textbox that appears, enter your preferred docker image.

For example, at the time of writing this, the LTS is 20.9, so I'll pick an Alpine image with node 20.9. So I'll enter `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:20.9.0-alpine` into the textbox.

However, after doing this, my provisioning works, but build never starts. I'm likely going to move away from using amplify to build my code and just use github actions.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to add `nvm install <node_version>` and `nvm use <node_version>` to the *amplify.yml* in *Build settings*:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm install 18.13
        - nvm use 18.13
        - npm ci
```